# react-router setRouteLeaveHook still updating URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-redux

I'm using react 15.3.1, with react-router 2.4.1 and react-router-redux 4.0.5:

When I trap the routing change with:

```
this.props.router.setRouteLeaveHook(
    this.props.route,
    this.routerWillLeave
);

private routerWillLeave = () => {
    if (this.state.editing)
        return 'You may have unsaved changes. Are you sure you want to leave?'
};
```

... I do get my `this.routerWillLeave` method called, but the URL in the browser still changes, so even if the user stays on the page by deciding not to leave the page, the URL is now wrong.  Ideas?

Comment: Hava the same issue, did you find a way to avoid this url changing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
export default class extends Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }

  state = {
    editing: true
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    this.context.router.setRouteLeaveHook(this.props.route, () => {
       if (this.state.editing) {
          return false;
          // At here you can give a confirm dialog, return true when confirm true
       }else {
           return true;
       }
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

And if your react-route >2.4, you can also use withRouter to wrap your component, this's may be better!

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router';

export default withRouter(class extends Component {
  state = {
    unsaved: true
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.router.setRouteLeaveHook(this.props.route, () => {
      if (this.state.unsaved) {
        return false;
          // At here you can give a confirm dialog, return true when confirm true
       }else {
          return true;
       }
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>About</h2>
        {this.props.children || "This is outbox default!"}
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```